# How to send JWT to front end server after successful login for storage on localStorage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

In my current application after the users logs in with google (passport strategy), I generate a JWT token on the server and then I have no idea how to send it back whilst also redirecting the user to the front end website.

While searching I read that the front end should fetch the token but does that mean I have to cache the JWT until it is requested and set some cookie with the key to get the token in cache? I tried doing that but that felt like I was reinventing the wheel and opening my self to some security vulnerability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer does not seem to answer the question.
It is a good answer for sending from the frontend (e.g. web application) to a backend (API or similar).

But I understand that you want to send the token from the backend to the frontend.
In this case, there are several way to transmit that token. They are widely used by OAuth2 Framework protocol.

##### Using a callback Uri

This is one of the most used technic. The backend sever generates a redirect response (status code 303) with the token in the query string. As an example

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: http://frontend.org/?token=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

You can also use a fragment property

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: http://frontend.org/#token=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

##### Code Exchange

Another method very similar is to generate a unique and one-time-use code that will be exchanged for the token using an additional request.

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: http://frontend.org/?code=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

On the fronted side, get the code and ask the token to the backend (using fetch)

```
POST /give/me/the/token HTTP/1.1
Host: backend.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "code": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

##### Possible Threats

There are several threats you have to consider. They are described in [RFC6819](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6819), but mitigations exist.

- CSRF attacks: Use a `state` parameter should be used ([section 3.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6819#section-3.6))
- Open Redirector attacke: you should not allow client to decide the redirection URIs ([section 4.1.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6819#section-4.1.5))

In addition, you should have a look at the [RFC7636](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636). This specification defines a way to protect the `code` against theft by using a random secrt generated on client side.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have 2 questions: is it unsafe to have the token in address bar? and would using a code in the query mean I have to store the jwt token in cache at the backend server, is node-cache viable for doing this?

Comment: Hi, I've just added few references about threat models. Hope it helps. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can send the JWT token in header or as a payload, and at the frontend you just need to attach the JWT token with every request when sending it to the server. The server should have the logic to validate before passing the request to next middleware if the token is valid the request will be passed to next middleware else unauthorised will be return.

You can send the token in headers, payload, query whatever you like, but widely people attach token in header under `Authentication`.

I recommend you checking [this](https://stackabuse.com/authentication-and-authorization-with-jwts-in-express-js/) link, it has step by step process to send and validate JWT token with Node and Express.

You can also check [this](https://www.bezkoder.com/react-express-authentication-jwt/) for node and react.

Comment: I stored the token in a header under authentication like you said but I can't manage to read it from the front end client? I did confirm that it was sent from the backend though
all I could find from searching was that it's not possible to examine the current page response headers.

Comment: You need to attach the token under authentication when there is no header with that key. You have to do this on the frontend with the subsequent request made to the server in order to authenticate them. Have you checked the links?

Comment: I have but they don't answer my problem. They are posting the username and password and then reading the servers response (all on the same domain), but since I am using google login, I am redirecting the client to the google login page then generating a jwt and then redirecting the user to the front end server with an auth header that I can not manage to read

Comment: In my case I have sent a token using : headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'x-access-token': `${token}`
         },